Does react new compiler offers the fresh loading of webpage from the server every time it renders the page?
My question is that if the react new compiler loads the content from the server every time content changes ?
**Note: I am note asking about the loading of entire page each time. Instead I am curious about the loading of changed/updated content of the webpage. **
Any help will be highly appreciated.
I am actually aiming to make a new project for my company but my concern is if I should choose React or not.

React Compiler only optimize React Components and Hooks. It has nothing to do with loading content from the server.
